# How to ignore same command after joining a Voice channel for bot discord.js

Tags: discord.js

How to make a bot to ignore the same command after the bot joins a voice channel?
So if a user with permissions uses a command more than one time, the bot will just ignore the same commands because it has already joined the voice channel (the bot will ignore `?zipfm`, but will not ignore others like `?disconnect` or `?leave`)

I tried making a cool down command, but still, if a user sends `?zipfm` command more than one time bot starts to search `dispatcher` again after every command so we need to ignore that command after first time use.

```
client.on('message', async(message, user) =>{
    if (message.content === '?zipfm'){
        
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === 'ZIP FM ')
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (!role) return message.channel.send(`ZIP FM rolė nėra sukurta. Rašyk \`?sukurti\` norint sukurti ZIP FM rolę!`).then(msg => {
        msg.delete({timeout:5000})
    })
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) return message.channel.send(`Ši komanda yra leistina tik vartotojams turintiems ${role} rolę.`).then(msg => {
      msg.delete({timeout:5000})
  })
        if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;
        if (message.member.voice.channel){
            message.member.voice.channel.join().then(connection => {
                connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
                message.channel.send("Paleidžiama ZIP FM ").then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({timeout:10000})
                })
                const dispatcher = connection.play('https://transliacija.zipfm.lt/zipfm128.mp3',{filter: "audioonly"})
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking if the message content is equal to `?zipfm`, you can simply use the [GuildMember#voice()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice) function in order to determine whether or not the client is currently inside of a voice channel.

You can simply do that using:

```
if (message.guild.me.voice) return message.channel.send('I'm already inside of a voice channel!');
```

Comment: It returns the message but still, I'm having the same problem...
After every `?zipfm` there is a small waiting time until the bot starts to play music again